# sns.countplot sum in one column issue

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I tried my first graph with `sns.countplot` and I had some issues/misunderstanding.

I have dataframe `target`:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 611 | 1 |
| 612 | 0 |
| 613 | 0 |

Only with 0 and 1, for length = 614

```
    target.value_counts()
1 422  
0 192
```

Now when I tried expose the result with `sns.countplot(target)`

I obtained this results :

[image: Result]

I was thinking of getting a chart with two separate columns (count 0 and the other column count 1).

I don't know where is the issue with my code.

Comment: `ax = sns.countplot(data=target, x='Another header')` or `ax = sns.countplot(data=target['Another header'])` or `ax = target['Another header'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', rot=0)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you are looking to plot two bars, one for zeros and another for ones, you can use a barplot using the `value_counts()` you have shown in the question. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
sns.barplot(x=target.value_counts().index, y = target.value_counts().values)
```